# inserting values from image file into 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, visual-c++

I have to read a file and put its values into an array in order to calculate the noise levels of the image. I can to all the later part of my program I just don't get how to insert the values into the array.

I have to read 10 image files and put all their pixel values(40000 of them) into the same table to later sort them. The pixels are to be read as chars and here is what I have written so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 ifstream f1;
 string entree;
 char pixel;
 unsigned char i = 0;
 unsigned char a[10][40000];       // declaration du table 40000 valeur

 while ( i <= 10)
 {

    cout << "Nom du fichier source :"; cin >> entree;
    f1.open(entree.c_str(), ios::binary);
    for (int j=0; j < 40000; j++)
    {
        f1.get(pixel);
        a[i][j] = pixel;

    }
    i++;

 }
 return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The habit of declaring all variables at the beginning of your function comes from old ANSI C, in C++ you usually declare variables just where you need them

Comment: Also what kind of pictures you are dealing with? What is their format? How their header looks like? ...